# Where should the Command and Command_CanExecute logic of my UserControl reside?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a view `PeopleView` that displays a list of `People` bound to a collection of `People` in `PeopleViewModel`.

In a panel within `PeopleView` I have a form (just a collection of text boxes and a button) which allows users to add a new person (`People`).

Initially I had this collection of controls as part of `PeopleView` but I want to separate it out into a separate UserControl (`AddPerson`) as it doesn't necessarily depend on the existing list of people and this `AddPerson` control could exist anywhere else in the application. I might want to reuse it elsewhere.

However, I'm struggling to work out where I should now be putting my button command and the associated CanExecute logic now.

It would have been in the `PeopleViewModel` but my `AddPerson` UserControl doesn't have a ViewModel. I've read that typically you wouldn't have a ViewModel for a UserControl, but I don't know how else I can make a reusable control that also contains its own business logic?

Should my `AddPerson` UserControl have a ViewModel, or should I be doing the business logic in the codebehind (seems very unlikely), or something else?

Comment: Your UserControl becomes part of your View, managed by your ViewModel. You don't need to change anything.

Comment: The only thing I would add to @McNets comment is that there's no hard fast rule that says your UserControl can't have a viewmodel for itself. Your command will go in a viewmodel. If your control is complex enough, it can have its own. No big deal either way

Comment: Thanks. The reason for not using the existing ViewModel is because if I wanted to reuse the control in another view, I'd have to duplicate the code for the command (and then maintain it), but it sounds like perhaps I should just create a viewmodel for my control, since it is in essence a view itself. It's just being contained elsewhere.

Comment: Do not make your control have a private view model. Commands are meant for communication between views and view models. If there is no view model, there should be no command, but just the ordinary event handling in the control's code behind.

Comment: @Clemens Is your view that I should instead be putting the logic in the button's `OnClick()` event then? That doesn't strike me a very sensible, MVVM approach...

Comment: Yes. MVVM does not mean that a control has its own view model. While you can of course implement it that way, it is uncommon. Controls typically don't have private view models. They do instead implement their logic in their code behind, for example in event handlers that are attached to their internal UI elements.

Comment: I'm not sure putting business logic, database calls, etc in the code-behind of a user control is a good idea. I've called it a user control because that's how it's defined in XAML, but it really is being used as a self-contained view in its own right. Thanks for your insight, though.

Answer (score 1):

Commands traditionally go in the ViewModel but there's no hard fast rule on this. If you'd like to make a more reusable control, you can create a command dependency property on the control itself and then bind it to a command in your view model when the control is implemented.

This is identical to how button command is implemented

For example

`MyUserControl.Xaml`

```
<UserControl x:name="self">
    <Grid>
       <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=MyDPCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`MyUserControl.Xaml.cs`

```
public ICommand MyDPCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MyDPCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyDPCommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDPCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyDPCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And then in your implementation xaml you can bind it back to your viewmodel

`MyView.Xaml`

```
<MyUserControl MyDpCommand="{Binding MyViewModelCommand}"/>
```

Comment: "you can create a command dependency property on the control itself and then bind it to a command in your view model when the control is implemented." - Unfortunately, this defeats main aim of what I'm trying to achieve, which is a self-contained and reusable control that I can place in another other view without also having to implement all the command logic multiple times.

Comment: @WSC have you heard of the service locator pattern? If not you should look into it. You can centralize your reused commands in a single location using this pattern. It also makes your command handlers testable https://stackify.com/service-locator-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've gone the route of implementing a `ViewModel` for my `AddPerson` view because, although it is technically a `UserControl`, I really am using it like any other view rather than a generic control.

Comment: There is no view or view model police that will come and smack your hand for doing this. If a user control is complex enough, you can absolutely have a view model for it. Nice work

Comment: It's more likely future me is going to do the smacking I come back to it later... (: